# Can I add a hyperlink inside a tooltip in an NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tooltip, nsview

I want hyperlinks in the tooltips of my OSX application, which then link to the Help Book in various places. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a tooltip is always placed next to the mouse with no possibility to click on it. But I guess you could achieve the look of a hyperlink by using `NSAttributedString`, although I'm not sure if the tooltips render them correctly.